# Missing command Get-ReceiveConnector in Exchange 2016 with Mailbox role

Tags: exchange-server

I have a new installation of Exchange 2016 Enterprise, Mailbox role (single server, no other servers in the infrastructure). Everything works fine but I need to make some configurations for which I need the commands Get-ReceiveConnector and Set-ReceiveConnector. However when I try to execute these commands in the Exchange Management Shell I get an error:

> [PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-ReceiveConnector
>   Get-ReceiveConnector : The term 'Get-ReceiveConnector' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - Get-ReceiveConnector
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-ReceiveConnector:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I can execute other Exchange commands successfully and Get-ExCommand gives me a long list of supported commands, but not the two I need:

> [PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-ExCommand
>
> CommandType     Name                                               Version
>
> -----------     ----                                               -------
>
> Function        Add-DistributionGroupMember                        1.0
>
> Function        Add-MailboxFolderPermission                        1.0
>
> Function        Clear-ActiveSyncDevice                             1.0
>
> Function        Clear-MobileDevice                                 1.0
>
> Function        Clear-TextMessagingAccount                         1.0
>
> Function        Compare-TextMessagingVerificationCode              1.0
>
> Function        ConvertFrom-SddlString                             3.1.0.0
>
> Function        Disable-App                                        1.0
>
> Function        Disable-InboxRule                                  1.0
>
> Function        Disable-UMCallAnsweringRule                        1.0
>
> Function        Enable-App                                         1.0
>
> Function        Enable-InboxRule                                   1.0
>
> Function        Enable-UMCallAnsweringRule                         1.0
>
> Function        Format-Hex                                         3.1.0.0
>
> Function        Get-ActiveSyncDevice                               1.0
>
> Function        Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics                     1.0
>
> Function        Get-App                                            1.0
>
> Function        Get-CalendarNotification                           1.0
>
> Function        Get-CalendarProcessing                             1.0
>
> Function        Get-CASMailbox                                     1.0
>
> Function        Get-ConsumerMailbox                                1.0
>
> Function        Get-DistributionGroup                              1.0
>
> Function        Get-DistributionGroupMember                        1.0
>
> Function        Get-FileHash                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Function        Get-Group                                          1.0
>
> Function        Get-InboxRule                                      1.0
>
> Function        Get-Mailbox                                        1.0
>
> Function        Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration                  1.0
>
> Function        Get-MailboxCalendarConfiguration                   1.0
>
> Function        Get-MailboxCalendarFolder                          1.0
>
> Function        Get-MailboxFolder                                  1.0
>
> Function        Get-MailboxFolderPermission                        1.0
>
> Function        Get-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration                  1.0
>
> Function        Get-MailboxMessageConfiguration                    1.0
>
> Function        Get-MailboxPreferredLocation                       1.0
>
> Function        Get-MailboxRegionalConfiguration                   1.0
>
> Function        Get-MailboxSpellingConfiguration                   1.0
>
> Function        Get-MailboxStatistics                              1.0
>
> Function        Get-MessageCategory                                1.0
>
> Function        Get-MessageClassification                          1.0
>
> Function        Get-MessageTrackingReport                          1.0
>
> Function        Get-MobileDevice                                   1.0
>
> Function        Get-MobileDeviceStatistics                         1.0
>
> Function        Get-OnlineMeetingConfiguration                     1.0
>
> Function        Get-RbacDiagnosticInfo                             1.0
>
> Function        Get-Recipient                                      1.0
>
> Function        Get-SiteMailbox                                    1.0
>
> Function        Get-SiteMailboxDiagnostics                         1.0
>
> Function        Get-TextMessagingAccount                           1.0
>
> Function        Get-UMCallAnsweringRule                            1.0
>
> Function        Get-UMMailbox                                      1.0
>
> Function        Get-UMMailboxConfiguration                         1.0
>
> Function        Get-UMPhoneSession                                 1.0
>
> Function        Get-UnifiedAuditSetting                            1.0
>
> Function        Get-User                                           1.0
>
> Function        Get-UserPhoto                                      1.0
>
> Function        Import-PowerShellDataFile                          3.1.0.0
>
> Function        Import-RecipientDataProperty                       1.0
>
> Function        New-App                                            1.0
>
> Function        New-Guid                                           3.1.0.0
>
> Function        New-InboxRule                                      1.0
>
> Function        New-MailboxFolder                                  1.0
>
> Function        New-MailMessage                                    1.0
>
> Function        New-SiteMailbox                                    1.0
>
> Function        New-TemporaryFile                                  3.1.0.0
>
> Function        New-UMCallAnsweringRule                            1.0
>
> Function        PSConsoleHostReadline                              1.2
>
> Function        Remove-ActiveSyncDevice                            1.0
>
> Function        Remove-App                                         1.0
>
> Function        Remove-DistributionGroupMember                     1.0
>
> Function        Remove-InboxRule                                   1.0
>
> Function        Remove-MailboxFolderPermission                     1.0
>
> Function        Remove-MobileDevice                                1.0
>
> Function        Remove-UMCallAnsweringRule                         1.0
>
> Function        Remove-UserPhoto                                   1.0
>
> Function        Search-MessageTrackingReport                       1.0
>
> Function        Send-TextMessagingVerificationCode                 1.0
>
> Function        Set-CalendarNotification                           1.0
>
> Function        Set-CalendarProcessing                             1.0
>
> Function        Set-CASMailbox                                     1.0
>
> Function        Set-ConsumerMailbox                                1.0
>
> Function        Set-InboxRule                                      1.0
>
> Function        Set-Mailbox                                        1.0
>
> Function        Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration                  1.0
>
> Function        Set-MailboxCalendarConfiguration                   1.0
>
> Function        Set-MailboxCalendarFolder                          1.0
>
> Function        Set-MailboxFolderPermission                        1.0
>
> Function        Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration                  1.0
>
> Function        Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration                    1.0
>
> Function        Set-MailboxRegionalConfiguration                   1.0
>
> Function        Set-MailboxSpellingConfiguration                   1.0
>
> Function        Set-MailUser                                       1.0
>
> Function        Set-SiteMailbox                                    1.0
>
> Function        Set-TextMessagingAccount                           1.0
>
> Function        Set-UMCallAnsweringRule                            1.0
>
> Function        Set-UMMailbox                                      1.0
>
> Function        Set-UMMailboxConfiguration                         1.0
>
> Function        Set-UMMailboxPIN                                   1.0
>
> Function        Set-UnifiedAuditSetting                            1.0
>
> Function        Set-User                                           1.0
>
> Function        Set-UserPhoto                                      1.0
>
> Function        Start-AuditAssistant                               1.0
>
> Function        Start-UMPhoneSession                               1.0
>
> Function        Stop-UMPhoneSession                                1.0
>
> Function        Test-SiteMailbox                                   1.0
>
> Function        Update-SiteMailbox                                 1.0
>
> Cmdlet          Add-Computer                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Add-Content                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Add-Member                                         3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Add-Type                                           3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Checkpoint-Computer                                3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Clear-Content                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Clear-EventLog                                     3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Clear-Item                                         3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Clear-ItemProperty                                 3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Clear-RecycleBin                                   3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Clear-Variable                                     3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Compare-Object                                     3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Complete-Transaction                               3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          ConvertFrom-Csv                                    3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          ConvertFrom-Json                                   3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          ConvertFrom-String                                 3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          ConvertFrom-StringData                             3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Convert-Path                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Convert-String                                     3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          ConvertTo-Csv                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          ConvertTo-Html                                     3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          ConvertTo-Json                                     3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          ConvertTo-Xml                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Copy-Item                                          3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Copy-ItemProperty                                  3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Debug-Process                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Debug-Runspace                                     3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Disable-ComputerRestore                            3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Disable-PSBreakpoint                               3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Disable-RunspaceDebug                              3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Enable-ComputerRestore                             3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Enable-PSBreakpoint                                3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Enable-RunspaceDebug                               3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Export-Alias                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Export-Clixml                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Export-Csv                                         3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Export-FormatData                                  3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Export-PSSession                                   3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Format-Custom                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Format-List                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Format-Table                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Format-Wide                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-Alias                                          3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-ChildItem                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-Clipboard                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-ComputerInfo                                   3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-ComputerRestorePoint                           3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-Content                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-ControlPanelItem                               3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-Culture                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-Date                                           3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-Event                                          3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-EventLog                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-EventSubscriber                                3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-FormatData                                     3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-Host                                           3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-HotFix                                         3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-Item                                           3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-ItemProperty                                   3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-ItemPropertyValue                              3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-Location                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-Member                                         3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-Process                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-PSBreakpoint                                   3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-PSCallStack                                    3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-PSDrive                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-PSProvider                                     3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler                           1.2
>
> Cmdlet          Get-PSReadlineOption                               1.2
>
> Cmdlet          Get-Random                                         3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-Runspace                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-RunspaceDebug                                  3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-Service                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-TimeZone                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-TraceSource                                    3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-Transaction                                    3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-TypeData                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-UICulture                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-Unique                                         3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-Variable                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Get-WmiObject                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Group-Object                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Import-Alias                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Import-Clixml                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Import-Csv                                         3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Import-LocalizedData                               3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Import-PSSession                                   3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Invoke-Expression                                  3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Invoke-Item                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Invoke-RestMethod                                  3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Invoke-WebRequest                                  3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Invoke-WmiMethod                                   3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Join-Path                                          3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Limit-EventLog                                     3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Measure-Command                                    3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Measure-Object                                     3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Move-Item                                          3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Move-ItemProperty                                  3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          New-Alias                                          3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          New-Event                                          3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          New-EventLog                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          New-Item                                           3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          New-ItemProperty                                   3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          New-Object                                         3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          New-PSDrive                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          New-Service                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          New-TimeSpan                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          New-Variable                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          New-WebServiceProxy                                3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Out-File                                           3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Out-GridView                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Out-Printer                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Out-String                                         3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Pop-Location                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Push-Location                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Read-Host                                          3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Register-EngineEvent                               3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Register-ObjectEvent                               3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Register-WmiEvent                                  3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Remove-Computer                                    3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Remove-Event                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Remove-EventLog                                    3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Remove-Item                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Remove-ItemProperty                                3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Remove-PSBreakpoint                                3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Remove-PSDrive                                     3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Remove-PSReadlineKeyHandler                        1.2
>
> Cmdlet          Remove-TypeData                                    3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Remove-Variable                                    3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Remove-WmiObject                                   3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Rename-Computer                                    3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Rename-Item                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Rename-ItemProperty                                3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Reset-ComputerMachinePassword                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Resolve-Path                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Restart-Computer                                   3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Restart-Service                                    3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Restore-Computer                                   3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Resume-Service                                     3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Select-Object                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Select-String                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Select-Xml                                         3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Send-MailMessage                                   3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Set-Alias                                          3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Set-Clipboard                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Set-Content                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Set-Date                                           3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Set-Item                                           3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Set-ItemProperty                                   3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Set-Location                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Set-PSBreakpoint                                   3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler                           1.2
>
> Cmdlet          Set-PSReadlineOption                               1.2
>
> Cmdlet          Set-Service                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Set-TimeZone                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Set-TraceSource                                    3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Set-Variable                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Set-WmiInstance                                    3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Show-Command                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Show-ControlPanelItem                              3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Show-EventLog                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Sort-Object                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Split-Path                                         3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Start-Process                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Start-Service                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Start-Sleep                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Start-Transaction                                  3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Stop-Computer                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Stop-Process                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Stop-Service                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Suspend-Service                                    3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Tee-Object                                         3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Test-ComputerSecureChannel                         3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Test-Connection                                    3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Test-Path                                          3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Trace-Command                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Unblock-File                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Undo-Transaction                                   3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Unregister-Event                                   3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Update-FormatData                                  3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Update-List                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Update-TypeData                                    3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Use-Transaction                                    3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Wait-Debugger                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Wait-Event                                         3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Wait-Process                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Write-Debug                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Write-Error                                        3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Write-EventLog                                     3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Write-Host                                         3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Write-Information                                  3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Write-Output                                       3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Write-Progress                                     3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Write-Verbose                                      3.1.0.0
>
> Cmdlet          Write-Warning                                      3.1.0.0

How can I get Get-ReceiveConnector and Set-ReceiveConnector to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this post https://tigermatt.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/missing-some-cmdlets-at-exchange-management-shell-me-too/ and it says that it's a user profile issue.

I tried using another user (the domain administrator) and everything works fine, so it's really a problem of my user. However, deleting the folder as suggested in the article didn't work.

What worked was adding additional roles to my user, especially the Organization Management and Enterprise Admins and now everything works fine.